# html table with enter event using jquery

Tags: jquery

though it is my first quesition, please help me, my question is I have html table  with input text in the third column, what I want is when ever I add values in the textbox and press enter then difference should be kwh - kwd and if the difference is less than value in the normal then bill is normal value but if the  difference is greator then difference bill should be difference * abnormal value, and focus should go to the next input.
this is my html:

```
<table id="adminTable">



        <tr class="tableHeading">
            <td>customer id</td>

            <td>kwh</td>
            <td>kwd</td>
            <td>difference</td>
            <td>bill</td>
            <td>normal</td>
            <td>abnormal</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>10</td>

                <td>9</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txt" id="name" class="name1"/></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>

                <td>6</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txt" id="name" class="name1"/></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>1</td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add whatever code you have tried so that it is easy to understand what you are trying to do and wanting to ask.

Comment: Welcome abdirazack, please explain your terms and perhaps show some of your code.

Comment: First of all, Its not a good idea to give same ID to more than one Input element.

Comment: please also add what you have tried in javascript / jquery so far.

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea about the jquery concept relating to this that that is why I did not show javascript code please help me I need it urgent.